# GeoServer GetFeatureInfo on RGBA 70GB raster returns empty feature response

Tags: raster, geoserver, getfeatureinfo

I have trouble getting feature response from GetFeatureInfo (to get raster values at a point) from GeoServer on very big raster - approx 70GB TIFF. Wierdly enough, the WMS service itself (GetMap) works fine and I am possitive, I am selecting bbox, which has data.
The raster itself is in projection EPSG:31258 while I am requesting bbox in EPSG:4326.

I tried both sending a direct request:

```
geoserver_url?service=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&
REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&
QUERY_LAYERS=layername&LAYERS=layername&
INFO_FORMAT=application/json&
X=10&Y=10&SRS=EPSG:4326&STYLES=&WIDTH=100&HEIGHT=100&BBOX=13.8480,46.6154,13.8570,46.6177
```

and using the Openlayers preview mode in GeoServer.
Both return a same 200 status response with empty feature set:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","totalFeatures":"unknown","features":[],"crs":null}
```

Preview mode returns the same but in HTML format.

The layer is set to queryable and other raster layers on same workspace yielded expected response with values of the raster in certain point.

Used GeoServer version: 2.12.0

[image: GeoServer OpenLayers preview]

The logs of the request do not tell me anything suspicious.

```
2021-01-31 19:37:06,396 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getFeatureInfo
    BaseUrl = xxxx
    Exceptions = application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage
    FeatureCount = 1
    Get = false
    GetMapRequest = 
GetMap Request
 version: 1.1.1
 output format: application/json
 width height: 100,100
 bbox: SRSEnvelope[13.848 : 13.857, 46.6154 : 46.6177]
 layers: xxxx
 styles: raster
    InfoFormat = application/json
    PropertyNames = null
    QueryLayers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@6b0e0587]
    RawKvp = {FORMAT=application/json, INFO_FORMAT=application/json, STYLES=, WIDTH=100, HEIGHT=100, LAYERS=xxx, EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage, REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo, SRS=EPSG:4326, BBOX=13.8480,46.6154,13.8570,46.6177, VERSION=1.1.1, X=10, Y=10, SERVICE=WMS, QUERY_LAYERS=xxx, TRANSPARENT=true, FEATURE_COUNT=1}
    Request = GetFeatureInfo
    RequestCharset = null
    Version = 1.1.1
    XPixel = 10
    YPixel = 10
2021-01-31 19:37:06,398 INFO [wfs.json] - about to encode JSON
```

Has anyone encountered a same issue? Could the raster size be the problem?

Comment: If you change the request to get map what do you see

Comment: I see expected map result - png image

Comment: First thing to do is move to a supported version like 2.18.2, then turn up logging level and try again